# Add SSH configuration rule for a given user on a given host

Tags: ssh

I use the password + public key double authentication by default for ssh connections on my host.

Content of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password
```

How to override this rule to allow the user `my_user` to connect with only the public key method but only when the connection is from the machine itself (localhost) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, add:

```
Match User my_user Host 127.0.0.1
    AuthenticationMethods publickey
```

Some more examples with `Match`: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Limit_access_to_openssh_features_with_the_Match_keyword.html